# How to plot multiple dates from BigQuery drop down into Google Data Studio

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a file in BigQuery which as dates as drop down menu. I have written a query and made a plot using the date 2020-09-13 but how do I use different dates to show the same plot in Google data studio.

Please see this image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxAKJ.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, or links). Also show us your current query attempt. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference)

```
SELECT ....
FROM `project.dataset.events_*`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhail.